# phonegap sqllite Database: the statement callback raised exception

Tags: ajax, database, sqlite, cordova

i am having this strange "the statement callback raised an exception or error did not return false"

it is  just a simple databases example.
my code is on github here:
https://github.com/prantikv/phonegapDBdemo

please read the comments in the code it explains everything.

i suspect the problem is in the ajax callbacks for the database.
if that is true than how can i make the ajax callback wait for data in sql-lite/phonegap?

```
function formSent(){//fired when form is submited
  alert("formSent called");
 db.transaction(queryDB, errorTrans);
 return false;
}
function errorTrans(err){ //error for formsent
alert("formsent "+err.message+"|"+err.code);//error is generated here
}


function createSuccess(){//just alerts on success
alert("DB Created");
}

function populateDB(tx) {//transaction obj is passed. Table Created not populated
  alert("populateDB called");
   tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS myDB (id , data)');
}

function onDeviceReady(){
 db= window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "Display Name", 4*1024*1024);
 db.transaction(populateDB, createERR, createSuccess);

}
function createERR(err){//error for create
alert("Create "+err.message);
```

}

AM i supposed to add return false for every database callback.if yes then which Boolean is to be returned when?

The phonegap doc examples dont have it http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/cordova_storage_storage.md.html#Database

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message usually isn't because of SQL, it is rather about exception that happens when you are executing callback for it. So you most probably have JS error happening.

I found

```
tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO myDB VALUES (?,?)', [username,email], insertSuccess, errorInsert);
```

on line *47* of *index.js*. It is lacking the *(id,data)* before *VALUES*. This causes the next SQL call

```
tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM myDB', [], querySuccess, errorSelect);
```

to fail. Fix that and then try again.

Comment: i did it it was actually an extra statement. i wanted to store the query in sql variable and then pass it to the tx.executeSql() method..corrected it STILL NOT WORKING

Comment: i was missing a tx object in one of the functions that was causing the problem